# Which test automation tools cover applications working on PDA with Windows CE?

Tags: automated-testing, mobile, mobile-automation

One of our customers from retail needs to identify test automation tools for different applications.

Currently they are evaluating Ranorex and Selenium.

They have some mobile applications also. For one of these applications they have a version which has been developed for PDA device working with Windows CE:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_digital_assistant

Can you advise us on test automation tools that cover application working on PDA with Windows CE ?

Answer (score 1):

If the PDA can be accessed by network (WiFi or Ethernet), you can use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) which use image reconnaissance and [Real VNC](https://archive.realvnc.com/pipermail/vnc-list/2002-September/033475.html) (or another VNC server).

Sikuli will have to run on PC with the VNC client connected to the VNC server on your PDA that will display it's screen.

I have used this method in the past on WinCE and it work well.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated to Sikuli or Real VNC.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing for a PDA app some years ago using TestComplete. They have a trial version available at https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/ which might be worth taking a look at.

Comment: The answer needs to be more than just a link! Write the solution here, use the link as reference and disclose your affiliation with smartbear if any!